# Exclude particular file (static resource) from being cached | Spring Boot Web

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application and below is the code for registrations of resource handlers:

```
@Configuration    
public class MyAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
       ...
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/js/**")         
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/js/").setCachePeriod(31536000);
          //in same directory where all the js files placed,
          //I want to cache all the files in that directory
          //except for one file i.e. prop.js
          /*registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/js/prop.js")
           .addResourceLocations("/resources/js/").setCachePeriod(0);*/
       }
       ...
    }
```

There are certain things I need to understand, viz.
 1. What does the parameter of `addResourceHandler` mean?
 2. What does the parameter of `addResourceLocations` mean?
 3. Is there any way to explicitly prevent `prop.js` from being cached?

There are may files at the same level where `prop.js` is, I want all other files to be cached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the `addResourceHandler` method, you specify URL, or URL pattern.
2. In the  `addResourceLocations`, you specify a valid directory actually containing (or possibly many directories separated by commas) the static resources.

So in the end, you made a simple mapping between URL ans directories on your web-server.

3. if you want to disable caching only for the file `prop.js`, try this :

   ```
   registry
       .addResourceHandler("/resources/js/**/prop.js")
       .addResourceLocations("/resources/js/")
       .setCachePeriod(0);
   registry
       .addResourceHandler("/resources/js/**")
       .addResourceLocations("/resources/js/")
       .setCachePeriod(31536000);
   ```

Comment: It should show some trace in response header as well right?
When that file is loaded, I am unable to see anything related to cache in response header.

Comment: @NisargPatil This is strange because in my case there is a `Cache-Control: no-store` header for this specific file. Maybe you should empty your browser cache and try again ?

Comment: Worked for me as well. Accepted the answer. Cheers!

Comment: Is there any way I can pick a particular file (say `prop.js`), and then update any particular header parameter (say `Last-Modified`) for that particular file only?