# Updating particular HTTP response header parameter for a static resource | Spring Boot Web

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to add/update a response header for a particular static resource (refer question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52518749/7088682)  for more details). 
I want to update/override parameters related to modifications of a file(`prop.js`) like `Last-Modified` in my case. I tried to achieve this in `addResourceHandlers()` of `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, but didn't find any solution.

Is there any way I can achieve this?
**OR** Can anyone help me with, where does spring sets headers for static resources? Because as I can see, when I update a file, value of `Last-Modified` value in response header is updated.

TIA